# Making the full SVG with an image inside as a selectable item

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

Currently I have an SVG component that has a border and inside the border there is an image. I am using these SVGs as markers on my map component so that when the user hovers over the particular marker, an event happens. With my current SVG this event only occurs when I hover over the border of the SVG and not the image. So is there anyway I can make the whole path of the SVG along with the image as 1 single entity.

CodeSandbox for better reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-gh75l

My SVG:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="85.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 850 1090" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path id="path" transform="translate(0,1090) scale(1,-1)" d="M406 1035 c-32 -49 -201 -104 -323 -105 l-43 0 0 -282 c0 -277 1
    -284 24 -333 39 -82 146 -174 291 -250 l67 -34 61 31 c151 76 265 170 303 253
    23 49 24 57 24 330 l0 281 -103 12 c-124 13 -206 42 -252 87 l-33 34 -16 -24z" />
  </clipPath>

  <image x="-200" y="30" width="1090" height="1090" clip-path="url(#clip)" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" />

  <use xlink:href="#path" fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="30" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Change your leave prop on the SVG to `onMouseLeave` not `onMouseOut`.

`onMouseLeave={() => { /* your setters here */ }`

Comment: @LyndenNoye what is the difference?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event "This means that mouseleave is fired when the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants, whereas mouseout is fired when the pointer leaves the element or leaves one of the element's descendants (even if the pointer is still within the element)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onMouseEnter` to `onMouseOver` and then the popup will stay as your cursor moves around the image.

```js
onMouseOver={() => {
  setSelectedProperty(item);
  setIsPopupShown(true);
}}
```